# Find specific field by value from query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM custom_fields_values WHERE `custom_field_value_for_item-id` = 1
```

which selects:

```
| custom_field_value_id | custom_field_for_item-id | custom_field_value | custom_field_to-compare_to |
|-----------------------|--------------------------|--------------------|----------------------------|
| 1                     | 1                        | test1              | 3                          |
| 2                     | 1                        | test2              | 4                          |
```

from my table.

How can I access the `custom_field_value` where `custom_field_to_compare_to` == `3`? And can I tell if this doesn't exist?

I know I could modify the query and just select it straight away, but I need to narrow down the *already performed* query.

Comment: Ist of all this is `custom_field_value_for_item-id unknown column

Comment: What driver use you? PDO, mysqli_ or... mysql_ ?

Comment: @fusion3k mysqli, sorry - I forgot to say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably make more sense to simply query the database again.

But if you want to search through the results that you already have retrieved, you could use for example [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

A simple example:

```
$search = "3";
$filtered_rows = array_filter($all_found_rows, function($value) use ($search) {
    return $Value['custom_field_to-compare_to'] === $search;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to just iterate over the resultset and find the row with the target value.

However, if you do not wish to use loops, you may want to look into [PHP LINQ](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/). With that you can do something like this:

```
// Assuming $result has the resultset from the query
$data= from('$result')->in($result)
            ->where('$result=> $result->custom_field_to_compare_to == 3')
            ->select('$result->custom_field_value');
```